# What is the difference between multiple try: except: functions and combining them?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, difference

I have two codes but they give different answers can someone tell me the difference?

This is the first one:

```
number_in_red=[]
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row +1):
    try:
        if 95<=int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[1:4])<=289:
            number_in_red.append(i)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            if 289>=int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[2:5])>=95:
                number_in_red.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                if 95<=int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[1:3]):
                    number_in_red.append(i)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    if int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[2:4])>=95:
                        number_in_red.append(i)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

How is this second one different?

```
number_in_red=[]
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row +1):
    try:
        if 95<=int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[1:4])<=289 or 289>=int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[2:5])>=95:
            number_in_red.append(i)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            if 95<=int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[1:3]) or int(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value[2:4])>=95:
                number_in_red.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: Since you do not tell us what `sheet` is, your code snippets are not complete. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet, if there's an issue with `value[1:4]` which throws exception (for example, it'll be a character which will cause `int()` to raise an exception) the code will continue and try to evaluate `value[2:5]` vs. the second snippet where it'll "jump" to evaluating `value[1:3]`